# Getting text from JTextArea, and calling it to the ActionPerformed method

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Okay. So I will start off and say this is ALL in one class.

Now, I have a bunch of buttons that are displayed on the GamePage to allow me to open up multiple different frames when these are pushed. So. I have the buttons all working, and all the frames open up perfectly fine. So now, Inside those frames that can be opened up, I have a JTextArea. Inside that JTextArea is where I allow people to enter what they want, and they press a button, and it will essentially get sent back to to actionPerformed method, in theory.

But...I haven't been able to get that to work. Here is the bare minimum that you will need.

**ACTIONPERFORMED METHOD**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getActionCommand().equals("M 100"))
    {
        math100();
    }
    if(event.getActionCommand().equals("Answer M 100"))
    {
        //THIS IS WHERE IF THEY PUSH THE BUTTON ON THE FRAME, 
        //IT WILL SEND THE JTEXTAREA TEXT BACK TO HERE. THEN IT WILL DISPLAY 
        //IF THE ANSWER IS CORRECT OR NOT. BUT I CANT GET THE TEXT TO BE 
        //SENT BACK HERE....
    }
```

**METHODS FOR THE QUESTIONS**
This is suppose to send JTextArea words that the users enter, back to the specific if statement in the ActionPerformed method.

```
public static void math100()
{
    JFrame m100Frame = new JFrame("100 Point Math Question");
    m100Frame.setSize(350,350);
    m100Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    m100Frame.setContentPane(pane);

    JLabel question = new JLabel("<html><p><div WIDTH = 320><center>Round 1,291,293 to the nearest thousands, and round 8.472 to the nearest hundredth.</p><p>Put answers in box below, and have the word 'and' between the two answers.</center></width></div></html>");

    JTextArea answerArea = new JTextArea("",10,25);

    JButton answerButton = new JButton("Answer M 100");
    answerButton.addActionListener(new GamePage());


    pane.add(question);
    pane.add(answerArea);
    pane.add(answerButton);

    m100Frame.setVisible(true);
    m100Frame.toFront();
}
```

What I want it to do is make it so that the JTextArea sends the text in that area, AFTER THE BUTTON ON THE MATH100 FRAME IS PUSHED, to the if statement, then checks if what they entered is right or wrong...But I cannot get the text to send to that if statement.

Comment: And do we really need all that code to help you further ? Strip it down to an minimal, compilable example that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us understand your code

Comment: Yeah, I cut down the code a bit. All you really need is the ActionPerformed and the math100() method, after that, I should be able to code the rest of the  methods. It still creates the same problem, where is doesn't send the text in the JTextArea to the if statement. How do I code it so that it does?

Comment: You need some kind of reference to the `JTextArea`, then you can simply call its `getText` method. Change `GamePage` to take a `JTextArea` as one of it's parameters in it's constructor

Comment: [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: How do you exactly do that? @MadProgrammer

Comment: @Nathan You change your `GamePage`'s constructor to require a `JTextArea`...if this is beyond you, I suggest you need to go back to basics before trying to tackle something as complex as a GUI

Answer (score 0):

Take The **JTextField out of the method** so the other methods can see it.

Example:

```
public class ho{

 (private or public) JTextArea answerArea;  

  public ho{.....}


  static method something(){

  ....}

  method actionListener(){ 
  ...}
```

Let me know if that works for you...